# Gaining weight without body building

Tags: training

can you guys please suggest me a dieting plan or something to gain weight or to add some muscle around my body and face. 
I'm a 21 year old guy , very slim for my age and want to gain weight really fast without body building.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, welcome to Sports beta on StackExchange. Your question fits probably better at our sister site http://fitness.stackexchange.com/ I have flagged this question so a moderator can look at it and decide whether or not to move the question there. Regarding your questions, I understand that you might not be happy with your look or fitness but you should also consider that gaining weight "really fast" is not a good idea and often not possible to get "beefed up" without a proper workout regime. Did you try to talk to a personal trainer at your local gym?

Comment: Yes all they tell is to work out to a limit where i cannot workout any more, what they want is to exhaust my self everyday and i don't want that ...i eat like a monster but no results where as my friends eat in small amounts and they are more healthier than me ... i just want to gain 5 - 10 kg of weight that's it ... @posdef

Comment: @Harry One, I wish I had your metabolism. Two, if you want to add muscle, then your personal trainer is right. You have to go beyond your comfort level to make progress...anything less than that is essentially wasted motion. Nutrition is so important. See Rory's answer below...

Comment: so what you are saying is that i exhaust my self daily upto the level where my arms and shoulders start to shiver ? @edmastermind29

Comment: @Harry Daily, no. During a workout, yes. If you push yourself to the limit during a given workout, your body needs rest. It had always been told to me, "at the end of a workout, you want to feel destroyed." When I was lifting, I only lifted once a week with [high-intensity training](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_intensity_training). My gains were big however...I went from leg pressing 135 to 295 lbs in nine weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rory Alsop's answer hits nail right on the head. I will try and expand on the concept to provide more details.

The energy metabolism is a very intricate biological network (see [my answer to a relevant question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6395/3464) for more details), with many components that can vary due to intrinsic (e.g. genetic variation) or external factors (environmental exposure or diet). There is essentially very little you can "ensure" without doing extensive studies on how **your** body *normally* works .

To put it in simplest terms, we have the following statements:

- weight = water + body mass (i.e. bone + tissue + ...)
- many factors of contributing to the weight is regulated tightly, for instance you will get rid of excess water.
- the body's biomechanical build up can be approximated by considering only bones and muscle tissue
- muscle is essentially a type of spring which can hold tension force by contracting (but not extension, in other words muscles pull, not push).
- given that you are not malnourished or have an underlying condition, your bone density will be exactly what you need it to be. In other words, bones get tougher over time, by undergoing tension.

To sum it up, your body will have the biomechanical setup that will keep itself stable. If you have high/fast-metabolism and do not train much you will most likely not have a large body frame and a muscular structure.

There are no shortcuts, and more often than not you cannot fool your own body. If you want to build up muscle you need to give your body a reason to do so (exercise), and the building blocks accomplish that (nutrition).

---

In response to OPs comment below:

Finding an optimum diet is a bit tricky but start trying. It's a good idea to get a quantitative feel for how many calories worth food you eat each day. You don't have to weigh everything you eat and look up in tables but at least get an estimate number. Then try to increase that number successively.

Also if you want to get a bit stronger/muscular you will need to increase your physical activity. You don't want to lift weights? Fine, no problem, you can work against your own body weight, try doing sit-ups, push-ups and pull-ups for a start. Working out more will make your body burn more calories, but you'll likely get more hungry as well. Try to make sure that you end up on the positive side with the calories, eventually you'll bulk up.

Comment: can you also please suggest a diet to match my BMI

Comment: @Harry I really can't, for two reasons: 1) I am not a nutritionist, 2) even if I was, it would be wrong and unethical to diagnose someone without actually examining him/her. I'll update my answer to give some *suggestions*

Answer (score 2):

Gaining weight is easy - eat more calories than you expend. If you find it very difficult to gain weight, it probably means you have a high metabolism and are burning more calories than you consume.

Gaining muscle is work - there are no easy ways round this I'm afraid. If you want muscle you need to persuade your body to make it, and that means using the muscle you do have hard enough that your body is forced to make more.

For rapid muscle gain, it's even harder work - you really need to push hard, exhausting yourself is very likely, and you need to eat the right foods.

And remember that your face may not be one of the places you will put on weight first - the waist is likely to be first for fat, and major muscle groups can bulk faster than small muscles.

Carbs and protein are essential to protect yourself from damage and provide muscle mass, and keeping well hydrated is also key.